# How to mount ext4 partition?

Tags: mount, ext4

How do I mount an ext4 partition as my user account so I wouldn't require root access to r/w on it? I used `-o uid=flint,gid=flint` on the `mount` command but I keep getting

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda7,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Another thing, I want avoid using `udisks` for now as it doesn't let me mount to my specified mount point name.

Comment: Can u paste your `df -h` output?

Comment: What specific command did you use? Please include all arguments, and whether you are using live installation.

Comment: Also check the smart status of the drive /partition from [Disks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-disk-utility/) , if found something unusual post the output of `sudo smartctl -HA /dev/sda7`

Comment: see if this helps http://superuser.com/a/348442/136930

Comment: I just realized `mount an ext4 partition as my user account`, so does it mount NORMALLY , or by selecting that partition from nautilus file manager. Is it another user's encrypted  partition.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't.  The files in the fs are owned by whoever owns them, and you can not change that at mount time.  Instead you need to change the permissions to give yourself access with `sudo chown yourname.yourname /path/to/mount`.  On a freshly formatted filesystem, the root directory is owned by root, so you will need to change it and from then on, you will be able to create new files which will be owned by you.

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksudo nautilus /etc/fstab
```

To mount the partition as "data" for example with read-write permissions add this entry in the /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sd8 /data ext4 defaults 1 2
```

Once the partition is mounted as "data", make yourself (my user account) the owner

```
sudo chown flint:root /mnt/data
```

and give yourself permission so you can access the partition

```
sudo chmod 700 /mnt/data
```

Comment: You missed the key part of the question: "as my user account"

Comment: @psusi this can be done as his user account.  He requires root to edit the file. right?

Comment: He is asking how to mount the fs in such a way that the files inside it are owned by his account instead of root.