# Cannot access /media/username folder - permission denied

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently and while installing I have created a separate partition `/media/username` in order to be able to share files with potential future installation as advised [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace). However, it seems I cannot access this partition - I can't see it in Files explorer and when I attempted to create and save a file there  through a command line I obtain `Directory is not writable` notice. The same goes with trying to move a folder to `/media/username` - `mv: cannot create directory './my_folder': Permission denied`. Moreover, I plug in the external disk and I can see it displayed within the same folder. What may be the reason of all of that?

Comment: I've reinstalled Ubuntu and renamed `/media/username` to `/media/data` but the issue persists.

Comment: Are the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/159992/590937) helpful?