# /media/data partition is not writeable

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I have installed Windows and Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot mode and I wanted to have a partition that would share the data between both systems. My partition is in ext4 file system and is mounted under /media/data. I can see it in Ubuntu files system but I can't write anything. How can I fix it?

I went for first option recommended by @vanadium and called sudo umount /media/data, sudo chown kuba /media/data, sudo mount -va but it didn't work - I still can't write anything on /media/data

Just to clarify - the partition is not visible in Windows, probably - as sugested by @vanadium, due to wrong file system. I present GParted view below:

[image]

How can I sort it all out? (Please note that I'm a new user to Ubuntu, so elaborate answers with console instructions will be much appreciated. I'll be happy to provide any additional info and console output.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to write to a partition, you need to have the proper permissions. Therefore, either

- Change the owner of the mount point of that partition (`/media/data`) to your own user.

or

- Set permissions for others to "Read, Write and Execute". This is a less secure option because then, any user, including users that log in over the network, can do anything on that partition.

Of course, you need to have administrator rights ("root") to change permissions.

You indicate that you want to share that partition with Windows. You should realize that Windows does not natively support the ext4 file system, so it will not be accessible from within Windows. The file system of Windows, ntfs, is preferred because Ubuntu supports it.

Comment: I went for recommended first option and called `sudo umount /media/data`, `sudo chown kuba /media/data`, `sudo mount -va` but it didn't work - I still can't write anything on /media/data

Comment: That is how it works normally. However, you said it is an ext4 partition, but as you say you share it with Windows, I find it hard to think that is correct information. Please verify the file system of your partition under /media/data. Add relevant information to solve your question to the question itself (use "edit"), not in comments.

Comment: I managed to solve the permissions issue accordint to this https://askubuntu.com/questions/159992/how-to-mount-ext4-partition/160013#160013 Then changed the filesystem via GParted. Unfortunetely, my Ubuntu doesn't boot at all now. I have created a separate subject for that issue - would you take a look? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207497/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-changing-partition-file-system-to-ntfs